# Why is my firebase document being overwritten?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am fairly new to Android development and the Firestore DB, I would greatly appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction.

I am creating an app that would allow a user to sign in, and I am using their email as the primary identifier for a document in the collection of "users". 
I want to be able to check if the users already exists using their email and if they do then return that an account is already registered with that email.

So far I managed to input user data into DB and query the DB to check if the user exists.

However my code overwrites the user with the supplied email rather than ignoring the write request and alerting the user that email already exists.

I already tried creating a private helper boolean function which I will call "checkIfUserExists()" that contains an emailFlag to query the db and change the flag to true if it exists and return the status of the flag, in which I would handle the call to write to the DB based on the result of checkIfUserExists()

```
    //Set on click listener to call Write To DB function
    //This is where my writetoDb and checkIfUserExist come together inside my onCreate Method
    submitButton.setOnClickListener {
        //Check to make sure there are no users registered with that email
        if (!checkIfUserExists())
            writeUserToDb()
        else
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Account already registered with supplied email, choose another.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
    }
//This should be called if and only if checkIfUserExists returns false
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private fun writeUserToDb() {
    //User Privilege is initially set to 0
    val user = hashMapOf(
        "firstName" to firstName.text.toString(),
        "lastName" to lastName.text.toString(),
        "email" to email.text.toString(),
        "password" to password.text.toString(),
        "birthDate" to SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US).parse(date.text.toString()),
        "userPrivilege" to 0,
        "userComments" to listOf("")
    )

    //Create a new document for the User with the ID as Email of user
    //useful to query db and check if user already exists
    try {
        db.collection("users").document(email.text.toString()).set(user).addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.d(
                TAG,
                "DocumentSnapshot added with ID as Email: $email"
            )
        }.addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e) }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

}

private fun checkIfUserExists(): Boolean {
    var emailFlagExist = false

    val userExistQuery = db.collection("users")

    userExistQuery.document(email.text.toString()).get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            if (document != null)
                Log.w(
                    TAG,
                    "Account already exists with supplied email : ${email.text}"
                )
            emailFlagExist = true
        }
    return emailFlagExist
    //TODO can create a toast to alert user if account is already registered with this email

}
```

Right now it alerts me that it detected a user with the given email in the DB, however it also overwrites the current user with the recently supplied information after I click on the submit button in the registration page.

How can I prevent this from happening and if you can also point me in the the right direction of best practices for FireStore/Android development I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `addOnSuccessListener` registers a async callback. And `checkIfUserExists` always returns false, because it finishes before receiving the response from the firebase (the callback execution).

One way to solve this issue, is to put your logic in the callback (call writeUserToDb in your callback method)